# Add/replace method from outside class

Tags: java

How can I add or replace methods (I need to do both) from the outside of an abstract class? I have the class code and can append code in an external .java file (sorry, I'm not a java expert).

Comment: Why? All you can do is adding/overriding methods in a class inheriting from the abstract class, but it won't extend the abstract class itself, of course.

Comment: I need to do this for a project of mine (can't give out a lot of details).

Comment: The question has too little context for a meaningful answer. What do you mean by "add or replace methods"? In the source code? At runtime? Dynamically? Please give an example of the situation where you need this.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that extends your abstract class. If yiu dont want to creta a new file for a class, you can creata a object by a annonyous class.

Comment: But, does it actually modify the class I'm talking about, or just create a new one that is identical? I'm not able to modify the code that calls the methods defined in the first class.

Comment: If you @Bogdacutu extend a class and override a method then any calls from the original class to that method will call your method definition.  Inside of your method you can call `super.method()` to access the original class.